# HERE SDK NavigationManager stop working when when I set custom LocationDataSource to PositioningManager

Tags: android, here-api

I'm new on HERE SDK and I faced with a problem related to `NavigationManager`. It seems to stop working when I set my custom `LocationDataSource` to `PositioningManager`. Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong?

In general, I need to change a default location provider that uses device GPS module to my customized location provider.

Comment: Can you please provide us some more information about the SDK release and the device you were using for testing? The Android release would be also interesting.

Answer (score 0):

please try checking if the datasource locations are actually matching with the map matching with HERE

> **isValidForMapMatching**(PositioningManager.LocationMethod method, android.location.Location location)

Can be called by the derived class to check if a location is valid for map matching.

please refer locationdatasource creation reference below :

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/common/LocationDataSource.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It turned out that the problem was that my implementation of LocationDataSource did not set the location timestamp. Adding this two lines solved the problem.

```
location.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
location.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos());
```